# UITableCell subclass never released?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, instruments

I'm using ARC but it seems that my custom UITableCellView is not release.

TBMListingLineView is a subclass of TBMGlobalCustomCell which is a subclass of UITableCellView.

In TBMListingLineView there are 10 UILabels (nonatomic, retain)

I've implemented in both classes the method dealloc which is never called (breakpoint doesn't stop the execution)

When I'm scrolling the TableView, the number of UILabel is increasing in Instruments/Allocations and that causes the application crashed after several memory warning.

[image]

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

TBMGlobalCustomCell* cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

switch(sortIndex) {
    case 0 :
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil || ![cell isKindOfClass:[TBMListingLineView class]]) {
            cell = [[TBMListingLineView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

    break;
```

....

```
return cell;
```

}

Comment: Why do you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` twice? And why do you check for `[TBMListingLineView class]` if your custom cells are `TBMGlobalCustomCell` objects?

Comment: Why do you call dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier twice? -> omg ... that's it ! Thanks ! To answer your second question, I have 5 differents subclasses of TBMGlobalCustomCell, and depending on sortIndex value, the TableCellView are different, THANKS again

Comment: But calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and then replacing the dequeued cell with a newly allocated one does also not make sense. Better use different cell identifiers for each subclass.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've just checked the documentation, I didn't know the aim os these identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` twice for each cell.
And then you "throw away" the second dequeued cell also if it does not have the right class.

A better solution is to use different cell identifiers for each cell (sub)class used in
the table view, so that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returns instances of the correct
class.